# Cant get the estimated time between two dates in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

how to get estimated time between two dates. 
I mean, $start_date - $end_date doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Carbon` to get the difference in days between two dates.

```
$end = Carbon::parse($module->end_date);
$start= Carbon::parse($module->start_date);

$days = $end->diffInDays($start);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper function to aid with this. `app/helpers.php`

```
<?php

if(!function_exists('days_between')) {
    function days_between($enddate, $startdate)
    {
        $datetime_end = new DateTime($enddate);
        $datetime_start = new DateTime($startdate);
        $difference = $datetime_end->diff($datetime_start);
        return $difference->d.' days';
    }
}
```

Inside the blade, you can call this as:

`{{ days_between($module->end_date , $module->start_date) }}`

Remember to include the helper file in the composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

and run composer dump-autoload to load the functions.